# Systemd running old version of NodeJS

Tags: systemd, nodejs

I am trying to running a server through systemd. However, I am getting an error due to a dependency needing an updated version of NodeJS.

The default version of Node on Ubuntu always seems to be 10.19.0 (for some strange reason), so I used nvm to update to the current lts version.

When i run `node --version` it shows the updated version and I can run the program with node and the correct version.

However, when I create a systemd service, it still runs 10.19.0. How can I get systemd to run the updated node version?